# Dynamically add buttons in Ionic to Nav-bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a nav bar and I want to add a save button to the nav bar for only one screen. I was reading the blogs and everyone was saying how you declare your buttons in the view and don't access them in a controller. That is all well and good but I have to imagine people still want to hide and show nav buttons. Am I missing something?

```html
<body ng-app="App">
      <!-- The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate -->
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button>    </ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <button id="saveButton" class="button button-clear">Save</button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>

      </ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add buttons on left or right side in navigation bar from any screen containing `<ion-view>`.Like

```
<ion-view title="New Screen">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
        <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">
            New Button
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-view>
```

So this "New Button" will only come for "New Screen".

Comment: Awesome, much easier than I was making it!

Comment: Good to know! I was starting to loose my hair on this one.

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to hide right nav button on that perticular. You can do it with

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right" >
</ion-nav-buttons>
```